# Why do we say " 'a' unit instead of 'an' unit

Tags: grammar, word-choice

As title suggest, wondering what the literary rule is for "A unit." Unit being a noun would need an article. I have generally understood that the a/an decision is if the vowel sound if the lead sound ex: "an hourglass, but a glass".

it seems to me very clearly the "U" sound is the lead here, but for word that start with the 'you-enn' sound (unit, uniform, unabomber), we use "a".

Comment: The “u” in “unit” makes the “Y” sound—a consonant sound—therefore you use “a” as  article. ***Unit***
noun UK ​  /ˈjuː.nɪt/ US ​ /ˈjuː.nɪt/

Comment: What is a vowel sound, may confuse you. As @Hachi says, the initial sound of this word is _not_ a vowel. However, I checked an old edition of Oxford English Dictionary, and they have some historical examples where they actually wrote _an unit_. See [this OED screenshot for _unit_](https://i.imgur.com/PFcD2nu.png). I think this indicates that the word was pronounced in a different way (by some, at least) at that time. Maybe pronounced like "oonit". I am writing this comment here (even if this is a duplicate thread) because you asked specifically about _unit_.